# Suppose N=p1p2...pn. If N=ab prove that a+b is divisble by a prime greater than pn

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing

Suppose $N=p_1p_2\cdots p_n$ and $N=ab$

Let $p_n$ denotes the $n$-th prime.

Consider $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$

Since $N$ is an integer $>1$ $N$ is divisible by a prime $q$
so $q\mid N$ but $q$ is a prime so $q\mid (p_1p_2\cdots p_n)$ (since it is equal to one of them)

Then $N-(p_1p_2\cdots p_n)=1$

I kind of got lost here and didn't know where to go from there.

Comment: I tried to reformat your question, but gave up.  Is $N=n$?  Is $p_n$ meant to denote the $n^{th}$ prime and, if so, does that subscript $n$ have any connection to the $n$ on the left in your definition $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$?

Comment: yes you are correct with subscripts N and n have no connection. I am sorry. Im new and haven't figured out subscripts etc etc

Comment: See the edit. Please let me know if there is anything in the edit that doesn't match what you have intended.

Comment: The body of the question seems to have little or no connection with the header.  For example, $a,b$ don't appear anywhere in the body.  Is the header question the one you want?

Comment: We always have $p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1>n$, so $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$ is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just address the question in the header.  That is, assuming $p_n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ prime we write $p_1p_2\cdots p_n=a\times b$. We now seek to prove that $a+b$ must be divisible by at least one prime $>p_n$

Suppose, to the contrary, that all the primes dividing $a+b$ appear in the list $p_1,\cdots,p_n$.  if $p_i$ is one of the primes in that last then of course $p_i\,|\,ab\implies p_i\,|\,a$ or $p_i\,|\,b$.  But then if we also had $p_i\,|\,a+b$ we'd see that $p_i$ would divide both!  To see this, suppose that $a=p_im$ and $a+b=p_ik$.Then we'd have $p_ik=p_im+b\implies b=p_i(k-m)$.  But if $p_i$ divided both $a,b$ then $p_i^2$ would divide $ab=p_1\cdots p_n$ But the latter is manifestly square free.  This contradiction establishes the desired claim.

Comment: Okay I was with you until the very end. can you explain the contradiction a little better?

Comment: I'll try.  $N$ is divisible by some prime, $p$.  Say $p≤p_n $  Then we know that $p$ appears in the prime factorization of $N$, hence it appears in either $a$ or $b$.  Let's say $a$, for convenience.  Hence $p\,|\,a$.  If $p$ also divides $a+b$ then it divides $b$ as well.  Write $a=pr$, $b=ps$ to see that $N=ab=p^2rs$  thus $p^2\,|\,N$.  But $N$ is visibly square free.

Comment: Note:  in the above, the first sentence ought to have read "$a+b$ is divisible by some prime, $p$".